# Preventing theorem title from moving with theorem content

Tags: tikz-pgf, thmtools

I am currently writing a document using **thmtools**, where i want to include **tikzpictures** centered in a theorem environment.

It works well when i have some text before the tikzpicture, however if the only thing I include in the theorem is a centered tikzpicture, then the title of the theorem moves with the picture.

How do i prevent the title from moving with the picture without adding some preceding text?

A working example is provided below:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\renewenvironment{leftbar}{%
    \def\FrameCommand{{\vrule width 3pt} \hspace{10pt}}%
    \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    headformat=\color{blue}\NAME~\NUMBER~ -- \NOTE\newline,
    headpunct={},
    preheadhook=\begin{leftbar},
        postfoothook=\end{leftbar},
]{base}
\declaretheorem[style=base]{theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}[Title stays]
    Some text.
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}[Title still stays]
    Some text.
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[gray, thick] (-1,2) -- (2,-4);
            \draw[gray, thick] (-1,-1) -- (2,2);
            \filldraw[black] (0,0) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west] {Intersection point};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}[Title moves]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[gray, thick] (-1,2) -- (2,-4);
            \draw[gray, thick] (-1,-1) -- (2,2);
            \filldraw[black] (0,0) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west] {Intersection point};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:
[image: The generated output]

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a MWE.

Comment: Thanks! Would you like me to edit the question, or to post a working example here as a comment?

Comment: It's better to edit the question. Just a suggestion: in case there is no text before `lstlistings`, try to see what happens if you add  `\eavevmode` in the place of text.

Comment: I have edited the question now to hopefully be more concise, and to provide a minimum working example. In order to cut down on the source code i now show the issue using tikzpictures instead of lstlistings.
@Bernard \leavevmode makes the title stay, but adds some vertical space before the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a workaround but why not putting a `\hfill` just after `begin{theorem}[Title moves]`. It worked for me.

```
\begin{theorem}[Title moves]
\hfill
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[gray, thick] (-1,2) -- (2,-4);
            \draw[gray, thick] (-1,-1) -- (2,2);
            \filldraw[black] (0,0) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west] {Intersection point};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{theorem}
```

[Updated answer after @Emil Njor comments]

Another workaround to delete the space between the title and the figure : add `vspace{-\baselineskip}` in the `center` environment. It is not very clean but at least it does the job.

```
\begin{theorem}[Title moves]
\hfill
    \begin{center}
        \vspace{-\baselineskip}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[gray, thick] (-1,2) -- (2,-4);
            \draw[gray, thick] (-1,-1) -- (2,2);
            \filldraw[black] (0,0) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west] {Intersection point};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{theorem}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This works just as the suggestion that Bernard proposed in a comment to my question. It makes the title stay, but adds an empty line of vertical space before the picture.

Comment: Sorry I did not see bernard's comment. I updated my answer. You can add a `vspace{-0.5cm}` in the `center` environment. It is not very clean but it does what you are looking for

Comment: That will work yeah, i used `vspace{-\baselineskip}` instead of -0.5cm, as i expect that to be a more general solution. As you say it is not the cleanest, but i will accept your answer if nothing cleaner is proposed.

Comment: You are right `\baselineskip` makes it more general. I updated the answer accordingly